# Python3 store link if it contains an item in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am gathering all the links from a single web page and trying to store only the links that contain the string in a list. I can get all the links using this:

```py
links=[]

for link in soup.findAll('a')
    links.append(link.get('href'))
```

That code works but returns a huge list of over 700 links. I want to get those down to only include the items in a list. I am trying to use the `any` function like this:

```py
list_of_keywords = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
links=[]

for link in soup.findAll('a')
    if any(word in link for word in list_of_keywords):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
```

But that returns `0`. I know that the words in the list are included in the links. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Assuming `link` is a string that contains `word1`, `word2`, or `word3`, something should be appended to `links`. If it isn't, your assumptions are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The `link` was being returned as a `bs4.element.Tag`. I had to perform the `link.get('href')` first. Once that was done, I could then check it against the list.